# C++ Three dimensional array random access performance

Tags: c++, arrays

I would like to boost the performance of application which stores 3D map. Currently, it uses QtreeNode as a structure for storing the map. However, accessing random position with coordinates x,y,z has a complexity of log2n.

I would like to store part of the map which I know is accessed 90% of the time in the static array defined as:

```cpp
Tile* tileArray[16][3500][3500] // [z, x, y];
```

The reason I set z as first dimension is that application iterations are usually done floor by floor and row by row like this:

```cpp
for (int32_t z = fromZ; z <= toZ; ++z) {
    for (int32_t x = fromZ; x <= toX; ++x) {
       for (int32_t y = fromY; y <= toY; ++y) {
            Tile* accessTile = tileArray[z][x][y];
      }
   }
}
```

Tile* is a pointer to a data structure containing information about that position on 3D map. Since the system is 64bit and the pointer size is 8byte and it takes a total of 1.5GB of RAM.

I would like to ask if there is some problem with random accessing such an array with x,y,z coordinates. Logically, the complexity should be O(1) but I am not sure about how CPU calculates the exact position in the memory.

I am not afraid of excessive RAM usage.

Comment: The position in memory is computed by offseting pointer, e.g., for `x`, `y`, `z` the address is `tileArray + 3500 * 3500 * z + 3500 * x + y`. To get the real performance you will have to do some benchmarks, but there is no doubt that this will be much faster than a standard `QTree`.

Comment: The complexity is not the only factor whicj determines speed. If your array is allocated on the heap, cache misses could be a determining factor as well.

Comment: What is the size of `Tile`? If you are sweeping over large chunks of the map at once, and this is done in the order of the layout, you might benefit from storing the actual data in the same order: that is put `Tile` in the map rather than pointers to the actual data. But this all depends on so many other details of the rest of the system.

Comment: First, it’s not clear but you don’t want to allocate each of those `Tile`s individually. Second, in modern C++ you don’t want to keep raw pointers. You’ll have to clean them up. Third, nested C-style arrays like that mean a separate lookup for each axis (IIRc). Why not use a `std::vector<Tile>` of size `16*3500*3500`? (Ideally you’d wrap that in a class to give nice 3D indexing.) Also, is it dense or will it be sparse?

Comment: Yes, I do not want to allocate all the tiles, that's the reason I use pointer. The Tile class contains two std::vectors and is derived  from parent class which has some more structures so it's not possible to store it in array/vector directly. Ben, is there some benefit of std::vector than array or just syntax? I think it is very similar or same in memory management or random access. As I said the program calls method getTile(x, y, z) and usually traversing only small part of the map with dimensions up to 15x15x15.

Comment: Since you're optimizing, i advice two things. 1. measure. 2. post, how exactly you're using your data. Because it matters a lot. For example your idea **requires** from you to rewrite all alghrithms that use it to go z, x, y to be cache friendly. Otherwise you'll have huge performance problems. If your data is sparse, then tree might be better. And so on, we don't have much data, so we guess.

Comment: @RadosławCybulski all algorithms already go z, x, y that's the reason I've chosen this type of structure. The only problem case as I mentioned down already is A* path finding which search path from posA -> posB but on constant Z (it's 2D only). At first it get's tile from posA and then go position by position to find its path but in max radius of 20. So probably switching X coordinate always copy different data to cache and may cause some caching problems.

Comment: That's really weird that he can even intialize that Array, for me I get out of memory errors note that: 3500*3500*16 = 196000000 ridicious amount of elements.